# How correctly convert this String using substring() Java method?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have the following problem using the **substring()** Java function.

I have to do the following operation:

I have a String representing a date having the following form: **2014-12-27** (**YEARS-MONTH-DAY**).

And I want convert it into a String like this: **20141227** (without the space betwen date component).

So I have implemented the following method that use the **substring()** method to achieve this task:

```
private String convertDate(String dataPar) {
    String convertedDate = dataPar.substring(0,3) + dataPar.substring(5,6) + dataPar.substring(8,9);
    return  convertedDate;
}
```

But it don't work well and return to me wrong conversion. Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Read the documentation of substring. The end index is exclusive.

Comment: Why not use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to replace all the occurrences of `-`. If the separator could be different then maybe using `SimpleDateFormat` would be better.

```
private String convertDate(String dataPar) {
    return datapar.replaceAll("-", "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use replace method which will replace all ocurrences of `'-'` for `''`:

```
private String convertDate(String dataPar) {
    return dataPar.replace('-', '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `replaceAll` (This ll **replace** `-` with `""` means it ll remove `-`) :

```
private String convertDate(String dataPar) {
    if(dataPar.length() > 0){
       return dataPar.replaceAll("-","");
    }
    return "NOVAL";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is only a date, you can use the `SimpleDateFormat`  and use a format like `yyMMdd` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

I want you to just change the end indeces of the substring() methods as given below

```
String convertedDate = dataPar.substring(0,4) + dataPar.substring(5,7) + dataPar.substring(8,10);
```

I tested, It works Fine as you requested :)

Answer (score -1):

```
private String convertDate(String dataPar) {
    final String year = dataPar.substring(0, 4);
    final String month = dataPar.substring(5, 7);
    final String day = dataPar.substring(8, 10);

    return year + month + day;
}
```