# Building a string pattern with two nested for loops makes the code too slow, with two separated, makes it to not pass the tests‽

Tags: java, string, for-loop, testing, concatenation

I am doing the following programming exercise: [Complete The Pattern #4](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55736129f78b30311300010f). The statement is:

> ### Task:
>
> You have to write a function pattern which creates the following
>   pattern upto n number of rows. If the Argument is 0 or a Negative
>   Integer then it should return "" i.e. empty string.
>
> ### Examples:
>
> pattern(4):
>
> 1234 234 34 4
>
> pattern(6):
>
> 123456 23456 3456 456 56 6
>
> Note: There are no blank spaces
>
> Hint: Use \n in string to jump to next line

I have tried the following naive solution:

```
public class Pattern {

    public static String pattern/*️*/(int n) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      for(int j = i; j <= n; j++){
        result += j;
      }      
      result += "\n";
    }
    return result.strip();
    }
}
```

Which runs out of time (the execution time is longer than 16000 ms) for input of three digits like: 496, 254, 529...

Then, I tried to simplify it, removing the nested loop and just iterating a first time to put all the numbers range, and then iterating a second time to append the rest of the pattern:

```
public class Pattern {

    public static String pattern/*️*/(int n) {
    System.out.println("n: "+n);
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      result += i;
    }
    System.out.println("result after first loop: "+result);
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
      result += "\n"+result.substring(i,n);
    }
    System.out.println("result after second loop:\n"+result);
    return result.strip();
    }
}
```

I have been debugging and I have found that this second solution outputs correct only when n is a one digit number. For example when n is 7:

```
n: 7
result after first loop: 1234567
result after second loop:
1234567
234567
34567
4567
567
67
7
```

However, when n is a two digits number:

```
n: 11
result after first loop: 1234567891011
result after second loop:
1234567891011
2345678910
345678910
45678910
5678910
678910
78910
8910
910
10
0
```

And the output should be:

```
Expected...
<...567891011
2345678910[11
34567891011
4567891011
567891011
67891011
7891011
891011
91011
1011
11]>

But was...
expected:<...567891011
2345678910[
345678910
45678910
5678910
678910
78910
8910
910
10
0]>
```

Being the test cases (extracted from the exercise):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class PatternTest {
    @Test
    public void pattern() throws Exception {
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 1 ), "1" );
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 2 ), "12\n2" );
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 5 ), "12345\n2345\n345\n45\n5" );
    assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 7 ), "1234567\n234567\n34567\n4567\n567\n67\n7" );
    assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 11 ), "1234567891011\n234567891011\n34567891011\n4567891011\n567891011\n67891011\n7891011\n891011\n91011\n1011\n11" );
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( 0 ), "" );
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( -25 ), "" );
        assertEquals( Pattern.pattern( -59 ), "" );
    }
}
```

I understand the bug is with `result.substring(i,n)` because of we are assuming that each number will count as 1 in the oop (will only have one digit), which is incorrect, it could have more digits...

How could we improve this code?‽

I have also read:

- [How correctly convert this String using substring() Java method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27314682/how-correctly-convert-this-string-using-substring-java-method)
- [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String concatenation (`String x = ....; x += "something else"`) is very slow; it creates an entirely new string every time, making a lot of garbage on the way.

Have a look at `StringBuilder`. This:

```
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) out.append(i).append(" ");
String x = out.toString();
```

is a lot faster than:

```
String x = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) x += (i + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in

```
result.substring(i,n);
```

If `n` is 11 your string has length 13 since it ends in `1011`. Since you want the substring to the end, you could do

```
result.substring(i);
```

but apparently the last ones should be `1011` and `11`, removing two chars at a time. You could use `(""+i).length()` to keep track of how long the digits are. However:

The integer calculations are trivial compared to string concatenation. I'd suggest your "naive" solution is fine and using `StringBuilder` as suggested by @rzwitserloot is all you need.